# How to check if the previous node is with a specific tag?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, domdocument

I have a DomNode:

```
<p>
 This is a test <xref>1</xref> in the XML <xref>2</xref>,<xref>3</xref>,<xref>4</xref>  bla bla bla....
</p>
```

With the command `getElementsByTagName`, I am getting all the `xref` from the paragraph `p`.

Now, I would like to know if before the selected `xref`, there is another `xref` or not.

For that, I thinked about using `previousSibling` and then check if the tag name is `xref` or not, but this is not working somehow.

Any idea on how to do that?

Here is what I was trying:

```
$refs = $paragraph->getElementsByTagName("xref");

foreach ($refs as $key=>$ref) {
   if ($ref->previousSibling->tagName == "xref") {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I got the same result as you in my [tests](http://codepad.org/GWrweRRt). Any `$xref->previousSibling` is not returning any other `xref` nodes at the same level, not quite sure why.

Comment: No idea, this is wierd.

Comment: The previous sibling of the xref node is a text node. Can you use `if ($key !== 0)` to test whether the node is the first "xref" node in the paragraph?

Comment: This wil not resolve my problem because if I do this on the 2nd xref: <xref>2</xref>, teh previous sibling is also a text node which is ","

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, perhaps the problem needs restating, as all the "xref" nodes in a paragraph have another "xref" node before them, apart from the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milos, I've come up with a workaround for your problem. It's not a beautiful solution but it does seem to do the job.

Since navigating through siblings doesn't work I thought of comparing the parent nodes for each of the `xref` nodes returned by the `getElementsByTagName` call, which goes something like this:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<body>
    <p>
        This is a test <a>0</a> <xref>1</xref> in the XML <xref>2</xref>,<xref>3</xref>,<xref>4</xref>  bla bla bla....
    </p>
    <p>
        <xref>5</xref>
    </p>
</body>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('xref');

foreach ($xrefs as $key => $xref) {
    if (!empty($parent)) {
        $previousParent = $parent;
    }

    $parent = $xref->parentNode;

    if ($key && ($parent === $previousParent)) {
        echo $xref->nodeValue, "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
2
3
4
```

#### [Working demo](http://codepad.org/Qu56uH3k)